# JHipster not receiving roles from Keycloak Users when login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jhipster, keycloak

I have a JHipster monolithic app with oauth2 running Keycloak locally. 
I don't know how exactly should jhipster work with oauth2... first I thought it would create the user automatically, but it didn't, so I configured keycloak: I created the `jhipster` realm, the `web_app` client, the client roles `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_USER`, and the users `admin` and `user` with their correct roles.
The problem is that when I login as admin it is not being recognized as `ROLE_ADMIN`, as a result I cannot access the administrator menu. So I started looking through the code, trying to understand how Jhipster receives the credentials from Keycloak, and I realized that the `OAuth2Authentication` object in `AccountResource.java` does not bring the `ROLE_ADMIN`, but the `ROLE_USER` which I don't understand why. The `OAuth2Authentication` object in json looks like this:

```
    {    
"authorities": [
        {
          "authority": "ROLE_USER"
        }
      ],
      "details": {
        "remoteAddress": "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
        "sessionId": "rkkveY_Xa5zFFd0SKu9Of_FLGRnbdiTPHdnpj4gc",
        "tokenValue": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1...",
        "tokenType": "bearer",
        "decodedDetails": null
      },
      "authenticated": true,
      "userAuthentication": {
        "authorities": [
          {
            "authority": "ROLE_USER"
          }
        ],
        "details": {
          "sub": "f348bbbb-9441-4543-9940-9da31e50d877",
          "email _verified": true,
          "name": "Admin Administrator",
          "preferred_username": "admin",
          "given_name": "Admin",
          "family_name": "Administrator",
          "email": "admin@localhost"
        },
        "authenticated": true,
        "principal": "Admin Administrator",
        "credentials": "N/A",
        "name": "Admin Administrator"
      },
      "clientO nly": false,
      "principal": "Admin Administrator",
      "oauth2Request": {
        "clientId": "web_app",
        "scope": [

        ],
        "requestParameters": {

        },
        "resourceIds": [

        ],
        "authorities": [

        ],
        "approved": true,
        "refresh": false,
        "redirectUri": null,
        "responseTypes": [

        ],
        "extensions": {

        },
        "grantType": null,
        "refreshTok enRequest": null
      },
      "credentials": "",
      "name": "Admin Administrator"
    }
```

here is the yo-rc.json:

```
{
    "generator-jhipster": {
        "promptValues": {
            "packageName": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "jhipsterVersion": "5.7.2",
        "applicationType": "monolith",
        "baseName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "packageName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "packageFolder": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "serverPort": "8080",
        "authenticationType": "oauth2",
        "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
        "enableHibernateCache": true,
        "websocket": false,
        "databaseType": "sql",
        "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
        "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
        "searchEngine": false,
        "messageBroker": false,
        "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
        "buildTool": "maven",
        "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
        "clientFramework": "angularX",
        "useSass": false,
        "clientPackageManager": "npm",
        "testFrameworks": [],
        "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
        "otherModules": [],
        "enableTranslation": false
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I guess this is because Keycloak gives the client roles in another claim "resource_access" and Spring Boot Security Oauth2 library doesn't read the roles here.

I have modified UserService.java to try at first to read this claim and the sub value corresponding to the clientId by decoding the JWT token, this is cleaner because it reads the client roles only.

```
   public UserDTO getUserFromAuthentication(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oauth2AuthenticationDetails = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication
            .getDetails(); // should be an OAuth2AuthenticationDetails

    Map<String, Object> details = (Map<String, Object>) authentication.getUserAuthentication().getDetails();
    User user = getUser(details);
    String tokenValue = oauth2AuthenticationDetails.getTokenValue();
    DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(tokenValue);

    Map<String, Object> resourceAccessClaim = jwt.getClaim("resource_access").asMap();
    String clientId = authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId();

    if (resourceAccessClaim.containsKey(clientId)) {
        ((Map<String, Object>) resourceAccessClaim.get(clientId)).values().forEach(rn -> {
            user.setAuthorities(extractAuthorities((List<String>) rn));
        });
    }
    if (user.getAuthorities() == null || user.getAuthorities().size() == 0) {
        user.setAuthorities(extractAuthorities(authentication, details));
    }

    // convert Authorities to GrantedAuthorities
    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream().map(Authority::getName)
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
...
```

Comment: Hi @Fabrice Dominguez I tried to set your code, but It says this class OAuth2Authentication or OAuth2AuthenticationDetails doesn't exist. Any suggestions

Answer (score 7):

In keycloak administration go to Clients >> YOUR_CLIENT >> Mappers -> Add new mapper -> Set mapper type to "User client Role" and "Token claim name" set to "authorities" and Claim JSON Type to string.

Comment: thank you for the answer, unfortunately I am still learning how to use the mappers in keycloak and now I have another problem with the newer version of JHipster. I'll be gratful if you could check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437540/oauth2authenticationtoken-not-been-recognized-in-getaccount-jhipster-6-0-1

Answer (score 2):

**New Solution**

You can see more in the link below the configuration of Keycloak, so it sends the roles in the token and we don't need to change the original code.

https://medium.com/@mobilegotop/how-to-configure-keycloak-for-jhipster-a-spring-boot-app-with-roles-709491e0b5c6

**Old solution.**
Not working so well, because the ROLES are not coming in the normal grant privileges
In UserService.java I changed like this:

```
 public UserDTO getUserFromAuthentication(final AbstractAuthenticationToken authToken) {
        Map<String, Object> attributes;
        if (authToken instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
            attributes = ((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authToken).getPrincipal().getAttributes();
        } else if (authToken instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken) {
            attributes = ((JwtAuthenticationToken) authToken).getTokenAttributes();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("AuthenticationToken is not OAuth2 or JWT!");
        }
        User user = getUser(attributes);

        JSONArray auths =  (JSONArray) attributes.get("authorities");
        Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<Authority>();
        for(int i=0; i<auths.size(); i++){
          Authority  au = new Authority();
          au.setName(auths.get(i).toString());
          authorities.add(au);
        }

        user.setAuthorities(authorities);
        return new UserDTO(syncUserWithIdP(attributes, user));
    }
```

and set the "authorities" in the token Claim Name like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've seen your video and do the same, but roles haven't been contained on user info yet. Please let me know do I have to grant "jhipster" scope to specific user or client?

Comment: Ahh, I missed the Token Claim Name, then it didn't. Thank you.

Comment: But now I have another problem, after login from keycloark successfully, jhipster requests api/account. Still, I saw the console, it doesn't have any token, it means after authentication, backend couldn't respond jwt token to client.

Comment: I solved this problem by remove two configuration lines .sessionManagement()
 .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)